# Is EVP_PKEY_copy_parameters:different parameters@p_lib.c:143 really an error ?

Tags: tls, certificates

I see that SSL handshake is complete but I see this following message as part of SSL errors. 
error::digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_copy_parameters:different parameters@p_lib.c:143

Not very sure if we can ignore that error.